# Добавление и проверка ключей PHP Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Целую ночь искал информацию по поводу добавления и проверки ключей PHP Mysql, нашёл только одну тему на форуме blast.hk, но тема была помечена как outdated, поэтому ничего не работает.

Помогите пожалуйста!

В одном файле(например: new.php) нужно добавлять ключи через форму в базу данных(ключ, срок действия в днях), В другом файле(check.php) нужно эти ключи проверять(Если ключ существует, то написать оставшиеся дни, Если срок действия закончился, то написать, что срок действия закончился)

Comment: Помочь с чем конкретно? Написать запрос вставки в базу? Написать запрос выборки из базы? Сверстать форму для указания ключа и написать обработчик сабмита формы?

Comment: А вы никогда и не найдете информацию по работе конкретно с ключами. Потому что в программировании надо изучать и учиться работать более обобщенно. Ключ ничем не отличается от любой другой информации. Судя по тому что вы написали он состоит из видимо текстового поля с ключом и срока в днях, который просто число. Значит вам надо ввести через форму текстовое и числовое поля. А в базу записать это текстовое поле и дату окончания (которую можно вычислить например прямо в mysql как `now() + interval ? day`, где вместо `?` подставляется нужная продолжительность).

Comment: Дальше вам надо получить из БД разницу в днях между текущей и записанной. см. функцию `datediff()`. Собственно все, разбиваем задачу на такие простые составляющие и ищем как делать каждую из этих составляющих